# CSS/Bootstrap - Move text to new row if it exceeds the column length

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

We have a column (the first of four), whose text may exceed the available column width. In that case we'd like to "send" that column into a new line below the other three elements (which remain in the first row).

Example:
[image: example]

If the first column with `verylongtext` would result in a line break,

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">verylongtext</div>
   <div class="col">1</div>
   <div class="col">2</div>
   <div class="col">3</div>
</div>
```

then it should become something equivalent to

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">1</div>
   <div class="col">2</div>
   <div class="col">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">verylongtext</div>
</div>
```

Is there any way to achieve this behaviour with bootstrap or other techniques?

Comment: The default bootstrap grid is rather not suited for this. If you’re okay with switching the source code order to begin with, you could put the “first” column last, and have the other three floating to the right. Then the content of the “last” column could come next to them, if there’s enough space. (That last column would only get a min-width instead of a width then.)

Comment: There is no way to do this with Bootstrap.

Answer (score -1):

if you want to keep fixed col width then use it like col-4instead of col. It will take care of large text , large text will go down long.

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve this using jquery the thing you need to do is to define the number of characters of what you are considering as "very long text", for instance, lets say that we defined it to 12.

Here it a snippet:

```js
var longTextLength = 12;
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("div.col").each(function(){
    //We look for every class called col
     if($(this).text().length >= longTextLength)
     {
      //If it's a very long text then we do logic
      //We look for the class parent
      var customDiv = $("<div/>");
      customDiv.addClass("row");
      customDiv.html($(this).get(0).outerHTML);
      customDiv.insertAfter($(this).parent());
      $(this).remove()
     }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col">verylongtext</div>
   <div class="col">1</div>
   <div class="col">2</div>
   <div class="col">3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I would do this using the [grid-model](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/layout/grid/): experiment with the various display sizes and see where the text breaks. Then hide it in that screensize using [responsive utilities](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/display/) and make alternate rendering visible for that and smaller sizes.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col d-none d-md-block">verylongtext</div>
   <div class="col">1</div>
   <div class="col">2</div>
   <div class="col">3</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="col d-md-none">verylongtext</div>
</div>
```

There's a [fiddle](https://mbaas2.jsbin.com/cirovad/edit?html,output) to see a working sample.

Another solution might be to use JS to detect the certical size of that first col and see if it use more than line-height...and if so, move it. But I think the first approach is far better (does not rely on JS, no screen-changes etc.)